# Installing Python 3.10 in Docker Image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker

I am attempting to install Python3.10 on a Ubuntu v20.04 Docker Image. I am using the line:

```
FROM nrel/energyplus:23.2.0

RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive TZ=US && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install python3.10 python3-pip
```

which seems to run properly, and I get a successful Image.

However when I run the Container, I appear to only have Python3.8 installed?

```
# python3 --version
Python 3.8.10

# python3.10 --version
/bin/sh: 3: python3.10: not found

# whereis python3
python3: /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3.8-config /usr/lib/python3 /usr/lib/python3.8 /usr/lib/python3.9 /etc/python3.8 /etc/python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.8 /usr/include/python3.8 /usr/share/python3
```

How can I install Python 3.10 in this case?

Comment: What image do you use? i.e. show FROM command or even better - the whole Dockerfile. And why not using existing images - https://hub.docker.com/_/python

Comment: Hi @Sergius: I am using "FROM nrel/energyplus:23.2.0" which Installs Ubunbtu 20.04

Comment: `dpkg -L python3.10` would be a place to start -- but really, we need a dockerfile complete enough we can run it ourselves as a [mre] to produce the problem on our own computers before we can test proposed answers.

Comment: `dpkg -L python3.10` gives me:                   
`dpkg-query: package 'python3.10' is not installed`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a closer look at the output from `apt-get` when you attempt to install `python3.10`:

```
root@3d5f9653d655:/# apt-get -y install python3.10
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libqgispython3.10.4' for regex 'python3.10'
Note, selecting 'libpython3.10-stdlib' for regex 'python3.10'
libqgispython3.10.4 is already the newest version (3.10.4+dfsg-1ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 23 not upgraded.
```

It treats `python3.10` like a regular expression, and matches it against `libqgispython3.10.4`. There is no `python3.10` package available, and if you were to use the `apt` command instead of `apt-get` you would get a better error message:

```
root@3d5f9653d655:/# apt install python3.10
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3.10
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3.10'
```

---

This behavior is documented in the `apt-get` man page:

> If no package matches the given expression and the expression contains one of
> `.`, `?` or `*` then it is assumed to be a POSIX regular expression, and it is
> applied to all package names in the database. Any matches are then installed
> (or removed). Note that matching is done by substring so `lo.*` matches
> `how-lo` and `lowest`. If this is undesired, anchor the regular expression with
> a `^` or `$` character, or create a more specific regular expression.

It's a dumb behavior, particularly because packages name legitimately contain `.` characters, but we're apparently stuck with it.